# What's the maximum area of a sector defined by an inscribed angle?

Tags: geometry

When $\theta$ is in radians, a central angle of $\theta$ creates a sector of the circle with area equal to $\frac12r^2\theta$. I started wondering what the area formula would be if the vertex of the angle was on the circumference rather than the center. But after searching on this site, I found that same question being asked. The answer was that there is no formula because a single value of $\theta$ can lead to different areas (rotate the angle without changing its measure to change sector area). So I have a new question.  What is the maximum sector area in a circle, when the inscribed angle is $\theta$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the base for a given angle is fixed, we just need to maximize the height

[image]

which requires $AC=BC$.

According to the following sketch we need to find:

$$ A=\operatorname{Area}\left(\triangle{ABC}\right)+ \operatorname{Area}(\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{OAB} )-\operatorname{Area}\left(\triangle{OAB}\right)$$

[image]

or also

$$ A=2\operatorname{Area}\left(\triangle{OBC}\right)+ \operatorname{Area}(\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{OAB} )=$$

$$=2\cdot \frac12 \cdot 2r\cos \frac \theta 2 \cdot r \sin \frac \theta 2+\frac12 r^2\cdot 2\theta=\boxed{r^2\left(\sin \theta +\theta\right)}$$

Comment: I think I understand everything except for one thing: how do we know that AC = BC?

Comment: What is the maximum distance between the chord and the circumference, that is the height?

Comment: @MumboJumbo The are for the circular segment $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{AB}$ is fixed. Then we need to maximize the are of the triangle $\triangle{ABC}$ and since AB is fixed we need to maximize its height which is of course obtained when the point $C$ is such that $AC=AB$. It seems trivial but we can also prove this fact if you have some doubt on that.

Comment: Is it because perpendicular bisector makes it an isosceles triangle?

Comment: @MumboJumbo Yes of course the maximum is obtained for the perpendicular bisector!

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically you could get $\theta$ closer and closer to a straight angle, and the area of the major circular sector (and circular segment) would get closer and closer to the entire circle.

Comment: It seems that the OP is looking for the maximum area for a fixed value for the angle $\theta$.